# Permissions Dropped after Package Failed

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, permissions, ssis

I created a local db and then set up a one-off job to copy the live db to this new db. Or at least that's what I *thought* I'd done. The logs suggest that the job thought it had to create the db on *live* and replicated to that instead so I *must* have set the job up incorrectly. The log shows that the table was created on live by the job.

For one or more reasons the copy job failed and the database it created was uloaded and apparently deleted (I can't find the `.mdf` or `.log` files) and this I could just about live with.

However after the failure of the job, all the object permissions were dropped from the live database so the accounts our application use to access the db were unable to connect.

After a restart the databases are running fine, but the permissions remain dropped.

I'd like to understand the reasons behind this behaviour and gather any dos and don't for the next time I have to do something like this.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you still have a copy of the package?

Comment: Yes - shall I post it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DB logins from live will overwrite your local DB logins. So, the local DB's logins, which contain the application user may be wiped out, unless it exists in the live DB also. Sometimes, the mappings between the DB user and the schema will get messed up. You can then recreate the user or use [sp_change_users_login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174378.aspx) to fix the DB user mappings.